# Problems when creating dynamic menu and submenu in vue 3 and sql

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am stuck with the following case, I am creating 1 dynamic parent menu and child sub menu, with vue 3 and sql server

I get the data from node with axios as follows.

```
  async datosProtegidoslogeo() {

  try {
    await axios.get(this.url + 'prindatosacceso', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'auth-token': this.token
      }
    }).then((res) => {

      if (res.data.status == 'success') {
        var dataDB = res.data.user
        this.datosdelusuario = res.data.user
        // console.log(dataDB)
        axios.get(this.url + 'principalmenu/' + this.datosdelusuario.id, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'auth-token': this.token
          }
        }).then((res) => {
          if (res.data.status == 'success') {
            this.menugeneral = res.data.data
            // this.menugeneral = res.data.data
            console.log(this.menugeneral)


          }
        })


      }
    })
  } catch (error) {

    console.log(error)

  }
},
```

where **this.menugeneral = res.data.data** is my array containing the list of menus and sub menus

menu test. vue obtain by means of 1 PROPS, with a v-for I go through and I am showing first the parents and then the sub-children, as follows.

```
    <li v-for="menudina in menugeneral" :key="menudina.IDMENU">
                <button type="button" v-if="menudina.POSICION == '1'"
                    class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
                    aria-controls="dropdown-example" data-collapse-toggle="dropdown-example">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true"
                        class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white"
                        fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M10 2a4 4 0 00-4 4v1H5a1 1 0 00-.994.89l-1 9A1 1 0 004 18h12a1 1 0 00.994-1.11l-1-9A1 1 0 0015 7h-1V6a4 4 0 00-4-4zm2 5V6a2 2 0 10-4 0v1h4zm-6 3a1 1 0 112 0 1 1 0 01-2 0zm7-1a1 1 0 100 2 1 1 0 000-2z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3 text-left whitespace-nowrap" sidebar-toggle-item> {{ menudina.OPCION}}</span>
                    <svg sidebar-toggle-item class="w-6 h-6" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <ul v-else  id="dropdown-example" class="hidden py-2 space-y-2 hidden">
                    
                    <li >
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                            {{ menudina.OPCION }}</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
```

up to this point it is displayed as follows

[up to this point it is displayed as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w78Q0.png)

**But I want to show the sub menus is not shown**

I am working with tailwind and with flowbite